# Is there a better way of re-arranging dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
    files = {
    'Input.txt': 'Randy',
    'Code.py': 'Stan',
    'Output.txt': 'Randy'}
```

I would like to return a dictionary where the keys are the names and where the corresponding value is a list of the filename:

```
    {'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```

I managed to do it with 2 for loops:

```
def group_by_owners(files):
    my_dict = {}

    for value in files.values():
        if value not in my_dict:
            my_dict[value] = []
            
    for key, value in files.items():
        if value in my_dict.keys():
            my_dict[value].append(key)

    return my_dict
```

Is there a more efficient / elegant way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***Option 1: defaultdict***

Default dictionary with a default value of an empty list, so you append values to it.

This solution is preferable.

```
files = {
'Input.txt': 'Randy',
'Code.py': 'Stan',
'Output.txt': 'Randy'}

from collections import defaultdict
inv_map = defaultdict(list)
{inv_map[v].append(k) for k, v in files.items()}

# {'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
print(inv_map)
```

***Option 2: Dictionary***

```
files = {
'Input.txt': 'Randy',
'Code.py': 'Stan',
'Output.txt': 'Randy'}

inv_map = {}
for k, v in files.items():
    inv_map[v] = inv_map.get(v, []) + [k]

# {'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
print(inv_map)
```

Comment: Just use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: The first option creates an empty lost no matter whether it's necessary or not.

Comment: Both options should use append. E.g., `inv_map[v] = inv_map.get(v, []) + [k]` should do `inv_map.get(v, []).append(k)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Actually `inv_map[v].append(k)` is sufficient.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for the comment, yet when running the alternative line suggested, the resulting dictionary is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this. Using `defaultdict` to avoid creating the initial list, and just use `append`

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group_by_owners(files):
    # Creates a dictionary that it's initial value is a list
    # therefore you can just start using `append`
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in files.items():
        result[value].append(key)
    return result
```

Comment: I would remove the apostrophes around value.